# Can I use **hitTestObject** with only the inside part of an object?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to use **hitTestObject** with only the inside (visual) part of the object, not the outside part or the border.
How can I use that?

Comment: Please try by yourself and share your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Right now your question is not very clear, and shows no sign of research effort.   Please edit your question to show what you have tried (post the current relevant code), and to clarify what you mean by 'visual' and 'outside' part of the object.

Answer (score 0):

By default, hitTestObject checks only the bounding box of the specified object to check for collision, which is the "outside" part you're referring to. There's another function, hitTestPoint() which checks whether a given point collides with another object, and hitTestPoint allows you to check for rough collisions (only the bounding box) or for precise collisions (the "visual" part only); however, it only works for a given point.

So, if you have two objects and you want to check whether their visual parts overlap, and not their bounding boxes, then you have two options:

1) Check only one point, e.g. the x and y coordinate of one displayObject, with the entire shape of the other displayObject, or
2) Create an invisible "border" of separate displayObjects which reside in the first displayObject, and check whether any of their coordinates collide with the "visual" part of the second displayObject.

In either case, you will have to use hitTestPoint(); this takes Stage coordinates, so you'll have to use `localToGlobal()` to convert it.

```
//where shapeAa is a shape nested within a displayObject 'shapeA', and you want to check whether shapeA collides with shapeB
var globalPt:Point = shapeAa.localToGlobal(new Point());
shapeB.hitTestPoint(globalPt.x, globalPt.y, true);
//...repeat for other shapes nested within shapeA, along its border, i.e. shapeAa...shapeAz
```

There's various libraries that allow you to test precisely for collision (and if you're using BitmapData instead of Sprite/MovieClip/etc. then you can check whether the objects accurately collide without the need of such libraries).